# Finding true anomaly without ambiguity

Tags: matlab, gps, complex-numbers, orbital-mechanics

I'm doing some computations on GPS parameters using Matlab. I have developed two equations for the true anomaly (orbital parameter).

[image: True anomaly equations]

Where "vk" is what I am trying to obtain; "e" is the eccentricity of the orbit and "Ek" is the eccentric anomaly of the orbit.

I want to extract the true anomaly without ambiguity using Matlab. I should convert the sine and the cosine of the true anomaly into a complex number and ask Matlab to compute the argument, I have tried but I don't know how to proceed to do this computation on Matlab. Any help?

Comment: Why don't you simply take the inverse of the right hand side?  I don't mean to insult your intelligence, but you can clearly see that `vk` is isolated on one side of the equation.  To solve for `vk`, why don't you just apply the respective inverse trigonometric operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your reasoning, but if you want to compute what you're saying at the very end of your statement:

> I want to extract the true anomaly without ambiguity using Matlab. I should convert the sine and the cosine of the true anomaly into a complex number and ask Matlab to compute the argument, I have tried but I don't know how to proceed to do this computation on Matlab. Any help?

... simply compute both of the terms, form a complex number and find the angle / argument:

```
S = (sqrt(1 - e^2)*sin(Ek)) / (1 - e*cos(Ek));
C = (cos(Ek) - e) / (1 - e*cos(Ek));
val = C + 1i*S;
vk = angle(val);
```

This is assuming of course that `cos(vk)` forms the real part of your number and `sin(vk)` forms the complex part.

Comment: Yes, I cannot use simply the inverse trigonometric functions because that way it creates an ambiguity. That was what I was looking for, thank you.